# Git "Cannot merge binary files" error in continuous integration build

Tags: git, merge, binaryfiles

We have an automated system which merges our development branch into a release branch.

> The merge is done via the command `git merge -s recursive -X theirs
>   development`.

The problem we encounter is that the merge fails on binary files when merging development into release.

> The error is: "`warning: Cannot merge binary files:
>   Resources/Main/Images/image.png (HEAD vs. development)`".

How do I merge the two branches **without user-interaction**? Everything coming from development into release is allowed to 'win' the merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a space in there after the `-X`, try:

```
git merge -s recursive -Xtheirs development
```

Answer (score 1):

`git merge` allows to use a merge strategy saying that in case of conflicts "our changes" always win or "their changes" always win. Use either

```
git merge -X ours ...
```

or

```
git merge -X theirs ...
```